# Can all Relational Alegbra queries be done in SQL?

Tags: sql, subquery, relational-algebra

I'm currently taking a Databases course in college.

We are taught that to write a query in SQL, you have to do the whole query in one statement (that is, one long line that ends in a semicolon). That is, we are taught that there is no way to construct a complicated query by

- creating a table with a query and "saving" that table someplace (perhaps in a kind of variable),
- then creating a different table with a different query and "saving" it,
- and then finally using those two tables (by, say, joining them).

However, you can easily write Relational Algebra expressions that do this.

One of my homework questions involves a lot of outer joins, and it would be much more natural / close to how I think about the solution, to take the above approach.

This has me thinking: are all Relational Algebra expressions possible to write in SQL?

Comment: Why can't ypu `select * from (select * from A) A outer join (select * from B) B on A.x == B.x`  Doesn't that work?

Comment: huh. it might! i'll have to try it out. i never saw the construction of (select * from A) A [ie exactly my wanting to "save a table from a query into a variable"] , and my professor was heavily implying that such construction didn't exist in SQL...

Comment: You _can_ "*create a table and "save" it*" using common table expressions: `with t1 as (select * from foo), t2 as (select * from bar) select * from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.other_id;`. For an example see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: You can also use temp tables... but you _should_ not do those things. Relational algebra is good, but using temp tables to accomplish it is very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes, any algebra expression can be expressed as a single SQL expression via subselects/subqueries. Also by CTEs (common table expressions) if available. You can express an algebra expression using multiple SQL expressions via adding views or (possibly temporary) bases.

You can nest SELECT statements. You must put them in parentheses and give them an alias (via implicit or explicit AS) in a FROM clause join. (Also commented by Jerry Jeremiah.)

```
select * from mytable join (select x from yourtable) s
```

That does *not* "save" the nested select value. (Aka derived table (value).) It gives a name for an arbitrary row from the subselect/subquery table that you are going to mention in conditions.

You can use CTEs and WITH. Again, that does not "save" a table value. (Also commented by a_horse_with_no_name.)

```
with c as (select a from yourtable)
select c from yourtable
```

You can CREATE VIEWs, which are populated automatically.

```
create view v select a from yourtable;
select * from mytable join v;
```

You can CREATE TEMPORARY TABLEs. (Later commented by Joel Coehoorn). (Or 
just CREATE permanent TABLEs.) You can INSERT into them then use in queries.

```
create temporary table t as select a from yourtable;
select * from mytable join t;
```